# JavaScript Debugging Centroid of Triangle

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging

I am trying to create a script that will find the centroid of a triangle given the three vertices (and show the work). I created this, however the answer that comes out is either random or "NaN". Please help with debugging.

```
var question = prompt("What do you want to know?")

if (question === "centroid of triangle") {
var Ax = prompt("What is the x value of point A on the triangle")
var Ay = prompt("What is the y value of point A on the triangle")
var Bx = prompt("What is the x value of point B on the triangle")
var By = prompt("What is the y value of point B on the triangle")
var Cx = prompt("What is the x value of point C on the triangle")
var Cy = prompt("What is the y value of point C on the triangle")


var MidpointABx = Ax + Bx / 2
var MidpointABy = Ay + By / 2
var SlopeDC = (MidpointABy - Cy) / (MidpointABx - Cx)
var InterceptDC = Cy - (SlopeDC * Cx)


var MidpointACx = Ax + Cx / 2
var MidpointACy = Ay + Cy / 2
var SlopeEB = (MidpointACy - By) / (MidpointACx - Bx)
var InterceptEB = By - (SlopeEB * Bx)

console.log("A: (" + Ax + "," + Ay + ")" )
console.log("B: (" + Bx + "," + By + ")" )
console.log("C: (" + Cx + "," + Cy + ")" )

console.log("Midpoint of AB (Point D): (" + Ax + "+" + Bx + "/2 , " + Ay + "+" + By + "/2)")
console.log("Midpoint of AB (Point D): (" + MidpointABx + "," + MidpointABy + ")")
console.log("Slope of DC: " + MidpointABy + "-" + Cy + " / " + MidpointABx + "-" + Cx)
console.log("Slope of DC: " + SlopeDC)
console.log("y-intercept of DC: " + Cy + " = " + SlopeDC + "*" + Cx + "+b")
console.log("y-intercept of DC: " + InterceptDC)
console.log("Line DC: y = " + SlopeDC + " * x + " + InterceptDC)


console.log("Midpoint of AC (Point E): (" + Ax + "+" + Cx + "/2 , " + Ay + "+" + Cy + "/2)")
    console.log("Midpoint of AC (Point E): (" + MidpointACx + "," + MidpointACy + ")")
    console.log("Slope of EB: " + MidpointACy + "-" + By + " / " + MidpointACx + "-" +Bx)
    console.log("Slope of EB: " + SlopeEB)
    console.log("y-intercept of EB: " + By + " = " + SlopeEB + "*" + Bx + "+b")
    console.log("y-intercept of EB: " + InterceptEB)
    console.log("Line EB: y = " + SlopeEB + " * x + " + InterceptEB)
```

}

Comment: Where is the error occurring? I tried this in Chrome, IE, and Firefox. It worked in all three with no NaN errors.

Answer (score 0):

prompt returns the data in string format so you have to convert that to an integer like this:

```
parseInt(prompt("enter x value"))
```